# TCL fails to expand environment variables

Tags: tcl

I have an environment variable which I can access without any problem when used in isolation

> puts "$::env(LIB)"
>
> > /home/asic/lib

However when I try and use this as part of a longer string, the env var returns an empty string!

> puts "$::env(LIB)/add/path/to/target"
>
> > /add/path/to/target

I am using Riviera Pro with $tcl_version=8.5 on a Linux system. It works fine on the Windows version.

How can I access the env var?
I have tried re-assigning to a local, but I still get the same issue. Neither do {} around the variable.

Answer (score 1):

The perils of different line ending conventions.

The script used to create the env vars was created on a windows system, and when the vars were interpreted by TCL, it was seeing control characters in the variable. Once pushed through dos2unix, the vars are now being used correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In standard Tcl, that code *as written* ought to work; the `$…(…)` variable form will not get confused by the surrounding `"…"` or by the trailing `/…` material. I don't know how Riviera Pro might be altering things, but I suppose that is possible.

What does `parray ::env` report? That should print all the environment variables and their contents. (The only really big differences between Windows and Linux with environment variables are that their names are case-sensitive on Linux, and each platform tends to have different characteristic variables set.)